# Question regards to definition of a limit

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, discrete-mathematics

The definition of the convergence of a sequence mentions that $\bar{x}$ has to be in $X$:
[image: Definition of convergence of a sequence]

However, when talking about limits (e.g. $\displaystyle\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}f(x)=L$), does $L$ have to be in the co-domain of $f$?

Comment: Do you mean the limit of the sequence $f(x_n)$? You didn't have any $n$ dependence.

Comment: I'd say yes. $L$ must share *something* with the values of $f(x)$, be it a metric space, a topology, something.

Comment: But see the comment thread under Ethan Bolker's answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Formally, no. If you define $f$ as the identity function with domain and codomain $(0,1)$ then
$$
\lim_{x \to 0} f(x) = \lim_{n \to \infty} f(1/n)  = 0 .
$$

That said, this formal truth is unlikely ever to matter in any significant way in interesting mathematics.

Comment: What does that value $0$ even mean there, though? As far as the domain and codomain are concerned, it doesn't even exist. If the question asked about the range, I'd agree wholeheartedly. (I agree in any event that this is mostly a philosophical question.)

Comment: @BrianTung Formally, the definition of a function specifies the domain and the codomain. In this case the codomain is a subset of the real numbers, from which it inherits the usual metric. So the definition of the limit makes sense. Hence the official "no" answer to the OP's question. But this is distracting fussiness when it comes to useful mathematics.

Comment: OK I'll accept that!